# Array reading as undefined/0 in JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a madlib type website and I'm storing the input values from the text boxes into an array using a for loop. Its giving me the error as followed:

```
script.js:67 Uncaught ReferenceError: madLibAnswers is not defined
    at submitButtonOnClick (script.js:67:92)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (VM147 madlib.html:14:76)
```

JAvascript

```
/*  
        __  _______       ___   _____ ___    ____ 
     /  |/  / __ \     /   | / ___//   |  / __ \
    / /|_/ / /_/ /    / /| | \__ \/ /| | / / / /
 / /  / / _, _/    / ___ |___/ / ___ |/ /_/ / 
/_/  /_/_/ |_(_)  /_/  |_/____/_/  |_/_____/  
                                                                                          
RUN THIS PROGRAM IN A SEPERATE BROWSER (hit the arrow in top right of the webview)
REPLIT DOESNT SUPPORT BROSWER HASHES/FRAGMENTS
*/



/* List that the answers save to */

/* Current madlib that the page is currently on */
var currentLib;
/* Number of words into the Madlib */

// Zoo Madlib text
var madLibZooTypes = ["Adjective", "Noun", "Verb, Past tense", "Adverb", "Adjevtive", "Noun", "Noun", "Adjective", "Verb", "Adverb", "Verb Past tense", "Adjective"]
var madLibParkTypes = ["Adjective", "Plural Noun", "Noun", "Adverb", "Number", "Verb, Past Tense", "-est Adjective", "Verb, Past Tense", "Adverb", "Adjective"]
var madLibArcadeTypes = ["Plural Noun", "Plural Noun", "Verb", "Noun", "-ing Verb", "Plural Noun", "Noun", "Plural Noun"]

function loadURLFragments() {
    currentLib = window.location.hash.substring(1)
    if (currentLib == "selected=zoo") {
        for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            document.getElementById('centerItems').insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<label  id="javascriptInsertTextbox' + i + '"></label>');
            document.getElementById('centerItems').insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<br>');
            document.getElementById('centerItems').insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<input type="text"  id="input' + i + '">');
            document.getElementById('centerItems').insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<br>');
            document.getElementById('javascriptInsertTextbox' + i).innerHTML = madLibZooTypes[i];
        }
    } else if (currentLib == "selected=park") {
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            document.getElementById('centerItems').insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<label  id="javascriptInsertTextbox' + i + '"></label>');
            document.getElementById('centerItems').insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<br>');
            document.getElementById('centerItems').insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<input type="text"  id="input' + i + '">');
            document.getElementById('centerItems').insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<br>');
            document.getElementById('javascriptInsertTextbox' + i).innerHTML = madLibParkTypes[i];
        }
    } else if (currentLib == "selected=arcade") {
        for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            document.getElementById('centerItems').insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<label  id="javascriptInsertTextbox' + i + '"></label>');
            document.getElementById('centerItems').insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<br>');
            document.getElementById('centerItems').insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<input type="text"  id="input' + i + '">');
            document.getElementById('centerItems').insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<br>');
            document.getElementById('javascriptInsertTextbox' + i).innerHTML = madLibArcadeTypes[i];
        }
    }
}
/* Zoo Madlib */
function submitButtonOnClick() {
    /* Park Madlib */


    if (currentLib = "selected=zoo") {
        for (let i = 0; i > 12; i++) {
            madLibAnswers[i] = document.getElementById('input' + i).value
            console.log("madLibAnswerswer: ", madLibAnswers[i])
        }
        console.log("currentLib: ", currentLib);
        console.log("madLibZooTypes: ", madLibZooTypes);
        console.log("submitButton: ", document.getElementById("submitButton"));
        document.getElementById('typeOfWord').innerHTML = `Today I went to the zoo. I saw a(n) ${madLibAnswers[0]}/* adjective */ + " " + ${madLibAnswers[1]}/*(Noun)*/ + " jumping up and down in its tree. He ${madLibAnswers[2]}/*(verb, past tense)*/ + " ${madLibAnswers[3]}/*(adverb)*/ + " through the large tunnel that led to its ${madLibAnswers[4]}/*(adjective)*/ + " ${madLibAnswers[5]}/*(noun)*/ + ". I got some peanuts and passed them through the cage to a gigantic gray ${madLibAnswers[6]}/*(noun)*/ + " towering above my head. Feeding that animal made me hungry. I went to get a ${madLibAnswers[7]}/*(adjective)*/ + " scoop of ice cream. It filled my stomach. Afterwards I had to ${madLibAnswers[8]}/*(verb) */ + " ${madLibAnswers[9]}/*(adverb)*/ + " to catch our bus. When I got home I ${madLibAnswers[10]}/*(verb, past tense)*/ + " my mom for a ${madLibAnswers[11]}/*(adjective)*/ + " day at the zoo."`;
    }
    else if (currentLib = "selected=park") {
        for (let i = 0; i > 10; i++) {
            madLibAnswers[i] = document.getElementById('input' + i).value
            console.log("madLibAnswerswer: ", madLibAnswers[i])
        }
        console.log("currentLib: ", currentLib);
        console.log("madLibZooTypes: ", madLibZooTypes);
        console.log("submitButton: ", document.getElementById("submitButton"));
        document.getElementById('typeOfWord').innerHTML = `Today, my fabulous camp group went to a (an) ${madLibAnswers[0]}/*adjective*/ amusement park. It was a fun park with lots of cool ${madLibAnswers[1]}/*plural noun*/ and enjoyable play structures. When we got there, my kind counselor shouted loudly, 'Everybody off the' ${madLibAnswers[2]}/*noun*/ . We all pushed out in a terrible hurry. My counselor handed out yellow tickets, and we scurried in. I was so excited! I couldn't figure out what exciting thing to do first. I saw a scary roller coaster I really liked so, I ${madLibAnswers[3]}/* adverb */ ran over to get in the long line that had about ${madLibAnswers[4]}/*number*/ people in it. When I finally got on the roller coaster I was ${madLibAnswers[5]}/*past tense verb*/ . In fact I was so nervous my two knees were knocking together. This was the ${madLibAnswers[6]}/*-est adjective*/ ride I had ever been on! In about two minutes I heard the crank and grinding of the gears. That’s when the ride began! When I got to the bottom, I was a little ${madLibAnswers[7]}/*past tense verb*/ but I was proud of myself. The rest of the day went ${madLibAnswers[8]}/*adverb*/ . It was a(an) ${madLibAnswers[9]}/adjective/ day at the fun park.`;
    }
    else if (currentLib = "selected=arcade") {
        for (let i = 0; i > 8; i++) {
            madLibAnswers[i] = document.getElementById('input' + i).value
            console.log("madLibAnswerswer: ", madLibAnswers[i])
        }
        console.log("currentLib: ", currentLib);
        console.log("madLibZooTypes: ", madLibZooTypes);
        console.log("submitButton: ", document.getElementById("submitButton"));
        document.getElementById('typeOfWord').innerHTML = `When I go to the arcade with my ${madLibAnswers[0]}/*plural noun*/ there are lots of games to play. I spend lots of time there with my friends. In the game X-Men you can be different ${madLibAnswers[1]}/*plural noun*/ . The point of the game is to ${madLibAnswers[2]}/*verb*/ every robot. You also need to save people. Then you can go to the next level. In the game Star Wars you are Luke Skywalker and you try to destroy every ${madLibAnswers[3]}/*noun*/ . In a car racing/motorcycle racing game you need to beat every computerized vehicle that you are ${madLibAnswers[4]}/*-ing verb*/ against. There are a whole lot of other cool games. When you play some games you win ${madLibAnswers[5]}/*plural noun*/ for certain scores. Once you're done you can cash in your tickets to get a big ${madLibAnswers[6]}/*noun*/ . You can save your ${madLibAnswers[7]}/*plural noun*/ for another time. When I went to this arcade I didn't believe how much fun it would be. So far I have had a lot of fun every time I've been to this great arcade!`;
    }
}
function logStuff() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        console.log('rah')
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body onload="loadURLFragments()">
    <div id="centerDiv">
            <center id="centerItems">
            <button id="submitButton" onclick="submitButtonOnClick()" type="button"> Submit </button>
            <br>
            <button id="consoleLog" onclick="logStuff()" type="button"> buton</button>
            <p id="typeOfWord"></p>
            <br>
            </center>
        <br>
        
        <br>
        <h1 id="titleHeader"> </h1>

        <br>
        <br>
        <label id="fulltext">
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I've tried moving the story variables around cause I find that JS scopes are a bit funky, i've tried making it a separate function. It just hasn't been working for me. All result in the same error but different line number(if I moved it) Worst comes worst I can just do all of it without the for loop and put it in manually but I really want to get this working. Sorry if im doing any bad practices im relatively new to programming.

Comment: Well, where did you define `madLibAnswers`?

Comment: is there any code missing here? I do not see where `madLibAnswers` is defined

Comment: @AGE should'nt this code block define the madLibAnswers?
        for (let i = 0; i > 12; i++) {
            madLibAnswers[i] = document.getElementById('input' + i).value
            console.log("madLibAnswerswer: ", madLibAnswers[i])
        }

or do i have to define it before hand

Comment: But you never defined it. How is it supposed to know madLibAnswers holds an array? You need `const madLibAnswers = [];` defined before you use it.

Comment: You need to declare `madLibAnswers` as an array before you start trying to access its elements as `madLibAnswers[i]`.

Comment: @RMof unfortunately no, you need to define it first just at the beginning of your submitButtonOnClick function, like this: `let madLibAnswers = [];`

Comment: Better define it as an object `let madLibAnswers = {}` to skip the array preallocation step.

Comment: Dope defining the array before hand worked. Thanks!

Comment: @Fractalism now i have a new issue, the array is becoming returning undefined, if i set some things in the array before the for loop it shows so i think the for loop isnt adding to the array